# Jquery Mobile List item alignment

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am designing a list view using jquery mobile like below

[image: Jquery Mobile Page]

I am trying to align the label and value as 30% an 70% respectively.

List view coding as below

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li data-role="list-divider">Account Information</li>
  <li>
    <span class="field_label">Label:</span>
    <span class="field_value">value</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="field_label">Long Label:</span>
    <span class="field_value">value</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS styles used

```
.field_label{
  width:30%;
}
.field_value{
  width:70%;
}
```

Still the label and value are not aligned.  What is the problem? How do I align?

Comment: use gird system http://jsfiddle.net/jz9vp/

Answer (score 1):

is an inline element and will not conform to the width you provided unless you specify display: inline-block

Comment: I set `display:inline-block;` for both the span tags, but now the value is showing at bottom of the label.  Can you please more specific? Thanks

Comment: Does it make any difference if you decrease the width of the two span? To investigate the problem try to set them respectively to 20% and 40%

Comment: If it makes the two span re-align on the same line, it probably means that it is just a question of margin/padding, which you could resolve through the box-sizing css attribute

Comment: No, 20% and 40% didn't bring the 2 spans on same line.

Comment: Can you please provide the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using either solution:

1. Using jQuery Mobile [*Grids*](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/grids/) and modifying `ui-block-a` and `ui-block-b` width followed by `!important` to force override.

   ```
   <li class="ui-grid-a">
     <span class="ui-block-a">Label:</span>
     <span class="ui-block-b">Value</span>
   </li>
   ```

   CSS

   ```
   li > .ui-block-a {
     width: 15% !important;
   }
   li > .ui-block-b {
     width: 80% !important;
   }
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/swkg2/)**
2. Loop through labels and check widest one, then modify width of all label according to the widest one.

   ```
   var width = 0;
   var length = $(".field_label").length - 1;
   var labels = $(".field_label");
   var count = 0;
   $.each(labels, function () {
       var init_width = parseInt($(this).outerWidth());
       if (init_width > width) {
           width = init_width;
       }
       if (count >= length) {
           $(".field_label").each(function () {
               $(this).width(width + "px");
           });
       }
       count++
   });
   ```

   CSS

   ```
   .field_label {
     display: inline-block;
   }
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/W4dB8/)**